# How useful would a pharmacist be in ancient times

Tags: science-based, medicine

Would a modern pharmacist be able to improve life expectancy of the known world by a huge margin if they traveled back to ancient times with none of their equipment  preferably around 1500bc Egypt

Comment: I don't know how useful a modern pharmaceutical education would be in the ancient world, since I don't think an education like that teaches you much of anything about how to get the raw materials to make modern medications.

Comment: Which ancient times and where? Egypt by Ramsés II time was one thing; it was something else entirely by the time of Cleopatra. China and the Americas were also very different in terms of medical science by those times.

Comment: Hi Razorlazer, this question is currently very broad and could use some more detail. It sounds like you've got two separate questions here that might be better asked as individual ones, and each of those could use some additional explanation for what you mean as "useful". Any human in ancient times could be put to use as a slave, but I imagine that's not what you have in mind. I've voted to place your question on hold so you don't get swamped with unhelpful answers before you get a chance to [edit] it with additional details.

Comment: It would still be useful to know whereabouts (environmental conditions depend on this). We could also use a definition of useful, useful to figure out efficient ways to kill livestock? To treat the wounds of a war, to preserve food maybe to prevent cholera? Please narrow your parameters.

Comment: 1500 BCE... Off the top of my head, the only two languages spoken in those times which a modern farmacist has a non-zero chance of even *beginning* to understand are very old forms of Hebrew and Greek. (Not yet Biblical Hebrew or Homeric Greek, but still well underway towards those.) How do you say acetylsalicylic acid in Mycenaean Greek? As for the chances for a barbarian slave (because that is what the pharmacist will become very quickly) to improve life expenctancy. they range between none whatsoever and infinitesimal.

Comment: Europe and Africa? This remains ridiculously broad in scope. Honestly, if you'd said "France" - it would have been too broad because of the variety of climates/tribal skirmishes. I concur with AlexP, language is super important, how is a polite, civilised person going to fit in with a warlike Germanic tribe's battle with the Gallic tribe's for example when he/she can't communicate with either? Africa or Europe 1500 BC is way too broad.

Answer (score 6):

You're asking two questions. Don't do that.

> How useful would a pharmacist be in ancient times

Depending on where they qualified and the nature of their qualification, potentially quite useful. [Pharmacognosy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmacognosy) is often a part of, or at least an optional part of a pharmacy degree. Whether they'd be able to apply that knowledge effectively is another thing altogether, but it would certainly be a good foundation. Whether they'd be better than a contemporary apothecary, I couldn't say, but with the aid of other modern medical knowledge (like germ theory) there's every chance they could be better in many other areas of medicine.

> what medical profession would be the most useful during ancient times

One who knows about [washing their hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignaz_Semmelweis).

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are clearly too-broad; it makes it much more difficult for the OP to clarify their question without invalidating existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

Pharmacists are well educated in the biology and chemistry of their profession.  While they wouldn't have access to the modern pharmacopeia, they'd have an understanding of how they work.  Given their training in science (scientific method, germ theory, etc) they'd be able to develop pharmaceuticals derived from natural sources like aspirin, sulfa drugs, penicillin.  Conceptually, they could extract morphine from poppies.  Even those few drugs would provide nearly miraculous treatments for things that killed people in those times.

Plus, their knowledge of hygiene would be huge -- take a bath, wash your hands after you poop, etc.  Even digging laterines properly would have a dramatic effect on the human population.  And, things like don't kill those cats if your village is infected by the plague.  Kill the rats instead.

The tools used by alchemists would be suitable -- with small modifications -- for the work.

Comment: Lots of people used latrines in antiquity; the important thing is siting them downstream of the place where you get your water from the river.

Comment: They need to be away from water sources by a specific distance and need to be a certain depth.  In early 20th century America,  improper outhouses resulted in near epidemic levels of ringworm.  But, educational programs to make them deep enough, made the distance of travel to reach the surface too far for the larva to dig.  That is the kind of hygiene information I am refering too

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, if he somehow finds himself in a position of influence**

But this would unlikely be a result of specific pharmacicst's training. Any modern health professional knows enough about hygiene, antiseptics and epidemiology to make general advice which can significantly improve average life expectancy. The biggest problem is to make ancient people listen to this advice. In a specific story, this time traveler may become a trusted pharaoh's advisor, just like Moses.

As far as specific pharmaceutical training goes, time traveler won't likely be able to synthesize any of modern medications. The gap in chemistry between 1500BC and today is just too wide. Again, if it is Ok to be story-based, our pharmacist can also be chemistry, biology and geology buff as well as a capable craftsman. This would allow him to outfit his own chemical laboratory and procure raw materials to produce a range of simple medications, like aspirin and some antibiotics. The complex ones, like human insulin, would be decidedly outside of his range.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the usual education of a pharmacist is much more about quality control and quantity control issues than it is about creating medicine.

However, pharmacists also know a lot about things like which common household materials are toxic, what to do about in a pinch and at a moment's notice, and such related things. If your child has chowed-down on your houseplant, and your houseplant is actually digitalis, a pharmacist might be able to tell you the best plan. Is inducing vomiting correct? Or should you be trying to get some counteracting agent into your child? Do you want a big old glass of very salty water? Or fingers down the throat?

Pharmacists will also have some idea about basic antiseptic practice, and basic first aid. They will be able to improvise things like alcohol for cleaning wounds. They will know how to make efficient bandages. They will know about sterile medical equipment and that a doctor should carefully scrub down between patients. Indeed before and after a single patient.

Pharmacists will know basic public health stuff. These are issues that were not well understood until just the last 2 or 3 centuries. Things like not letting waste (urine or feces) get into the drinking water. Including both human and animal waste. And not letting other foul material near the food or water.

Pharmacists will know low level surgical stuff like how to lance a boil, how to treat a small cut or burn. They will most probably know how to deal with a simple broken bone, though maybe not with a compound fracture. Even there they will be able to lower the chance of infection, and lower the bad consequences of infection when it does happen.

And they might know some very basic things. Like how to make aspirin, or how to treat malaria.

Comment: I suppose you beliebe that the Romans built those sewers and those aqueducts for fun. Hint: they were *very* expensive and *very* labor intensive. Some of them are still in use...

Comment: Making aspirin is surprisingly awkward... it involves a non-trivial amount of chemistry that isn't necessarily within the remit of a pharmacist. It isn't simply an extract of willow bark. Refining opium into morphine seems somewhat more straightfoward.

Comment: Re: Romans and public health. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disease_in_Imperial_Rome

Answer (score -1):

Antibiotics are probably one of the most useful things I can think would improve survival in the absence of all the other tools available to modern medics.

Comment: No. Antibiotics in the hands of nowadays people are the great evolver for superbugs. In the hands of the ancients you're just giving them a few millenia of a headstart.

Comment: Antiseptics and cleanliness, however, would be a huge benefit. Someone who knows how to make a functional still might be more useful than someone who knows the modern pharmacopeia, and a scientifically trained herbalist more useful than someone who knows how to compound complex drugs from modern materials.

Comment: I get where you’re coming from but I suggested this on the back of working as a critical care physician for the last 20 years. I’d say judicious use of antibiotics is lifesaving. Antisepsis can prevent infection but once you get it (and in the past E.g. plague, scarlet fever etc) the only cure is antibiotics. Yes you can get resistance but if used appropriately the one is life saving. The other is beneficial./preventative but isnt going to have an impact on an established infection and even in clean environments infections do crop up simply by close contact. Meningitis etc